# Difficulty printing data in my binary tree in print method

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm trying to add data to a binary tree, however when I run a method that prints the data of the binarytree in order, nothing prints, and the program exits when it should be printing. I've tested it to see if data is actually being added by having the name and weight values of the rootNode print themselves inside the add method everytime its called, but I cannot get the same results inside of the inOrder method. I believe my issue has something to do with the node being passed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int weight;
    string name;

    node *left, *right;
};

struct node* newNode(int dataw, string datan)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->weight = dataw;
    node->name = datan;

    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return (node);
}



void add(node *rootNode, int dataw, string datan)
{
    int lowest_weight;
    if (rootNode == NULL )
    {
        rootNode = newNode(dataw,datan);
        lowest_weight = dataw;
    }
    else
    {
        if (datan < rootNode->name)
        {
            if (rootNode->left == NULL)
            {
                rootNode->left = newNode(dataw,datan);
            }
            else
            {
                add(rootNode->left,dataw,datan);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (rootNode->right == NULL)
            {
                rootNode->right = newNode(dataw,datan);
            }
            else
            {
                add(rootNode->right, dataw, datan);
            }
        }
    }
}

void inOrder(node *next)
{
    if (next!=NULL)
    {
        inOrder(next->left);
        cout << next->name << " " << next->weight << endl;
        inOrder(next->right);
    }
}


int main()
{
    node *rootNode = NULL;
    int height {}, leaves {}, weight {};
    string name;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        cin >> name;
        if (name == "-1")
            break;

        cout << "Enter weight: ";
        cin >> weight;

        add(rootNode, weight, name);

    } while (name!="-1");

    inOrder(rootNode);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, had to assign the rootNode declaration to a new node method call so the data is not always NULL

```
node *rootNode = newNode(weight,name);
```